# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client on res.writeHead

Tags: node.js, express

I am hitting the following error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

The following `server.js` contains a route which pulls some data from MySQL and if the data size exceeds a certain limit (currently 1 byte for testing purposes) then instead of returning the data, it needs to upload it to an S3 and created a signed URL. In order to do this, it calls on my `s3DataMitigation.js` file. Once it has the signed URL, it should redirect with a 303 SEE OTHER header to the signed URL on S3 (actually using res.writeHead currently) and it actually does redirect. However, in my console log I am still seeing a build fail because of this error.

On a side note, I may have included too much code. Feel free to edit it down if so.

```
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");

//Setup paths to database connection pools
const nawfprojectsDB = require("../lib/naWfProjectsDb.js");
const queries = require("./queries.js");

//Setup a timestamp for logging
const timestamp = new Date().toString();

// create the server and setup routes
const app = express();

// S3 Data Mitigation is needed when a data set exceeds 5 MB in size.
// This is a restriction of Lambda itself (they say 6 MB but want to ensure we dont ever hit the limit)
const s3DataMitigation = require("../lib/s3DataMitigation.js");

//Here we config CORS and enable for all routes
var whitelist = [
  "localhost",
  "url1", //In my code I use actual URLs here
  "url2",
  "url3",
];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: whitelist,
  credentials: true,
};
// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Size conversion
const dataSizeLimit = 1;

//
// Setup routes
//
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Nothing avail at root"));

//brabbit data table for workgroup data
app.get("/wg_data", (req, res, callback) => {
  const dataSet = "wg_data";
  nawfprojectsDB.query(queries.wg_data, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    //Stringify our results for S3 to understand
    const data = JSON.stringify(result);
    if (Buffer.byteLength(data, "utf-8") > dataSizeLimit) {
      console.log(timestamp, "Running s3DataMitigation...");

      s3DataMitigation({ dataSet, data, res, callback });
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
    console.log(
      timestamp,
      "Returned " + result.length + " rows from  " + dataSet
    );
  });
  // const user = req.query.user;
  // usageLog({ dataSet, user });
});
```

And here is `s3DataMitigation.js`

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const s3DataMitigation = ({ dataSet, data, res, callback }) => {
  //Setup a timestamp for logging
  const timestamp = new Date().toString();

  aws.config = {
    accessKeyId: "accessKey",
    secretAccessKey: "secretKey",
    region: "us-east-1",
  };

  // Setup S3
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  // Build the file name using UUID to make the file name unique
  const fileName = dataSet + uuidv4() + ".json";
  const bucket = "data-mitigation";
  // Setup S3 parameters for upload
  const s3UploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: fileName,
    Body: data,
    ContentType: "application/json",
  };

  // Using aws-sdk we programatically create the file in our S3
  s3.putObject(s3UploadParams)
    .promise()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(timestamp, "complete:PUT Object", data);

      // We want to wait until we can confirm the file exists in S3 before proceeding, thus we continue code within this block
      var signedUrlParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 60 * 5,
        ResponseContentType: "application/json",
      };

      s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", signedUrlParams, function (err, url) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(url);
        res.writeHead(302, {
          Location: url,
          //add other headers here...
        });
        res.end();
      });
      callback(null, data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(timestamp, "failure:PUT Object", err);
      callback(err);
    });
};

module.exports = s3DataMitigation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In s3DataMitigation, there is a statement you're calling callback, try my code below. I have include some explanatory comments.

```
   const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const s3DataMitigation = ({ dataSet, data, res, callback }) => {
  //Setup a timestamp for logging
  const timestamp = new Date().toString();

  aws.config = {
    accessKeyId: "accessKey",
    secretAccessKey: "secretKey",
    region: "us-east-1",
  };

  // Setup S3
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  // Build the file name using UUID to make the file name unique
  const fileName = dataSet + uuidv4() + ".json";
  const bucket = "data-mitigation";
  // Setup S3 parameters for upload
  const s3UploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: fileName,
    Body: data,
    ContentType: "application/json",
  };

  // Using aws-sdk we programatically create the file in our S3
  s3.putObject(s3UploadParams)
    .promise()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(timestamp, "complete:PUT Object", data);

      // We want to wait until we can confirm the file exists in S3 before proceeding, thus we continue code within this block
      var signedUrlParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 60 * 5,
        ResponseContentType: "application/json",
      };

      s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", signedUrlParams, function (err, url) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(url);
        res.writeHead(302, {
          Location: url,
          //add other headers here...
        });
        res.end(); 
      });
     // callback(null, data); // this line is causing you all the trouble
     // what it does is to bubble down the request to default handlers (error handlers etc )
     // but at this stage, the request has already been resolved by redirect above
     // hence the error, cause it will try to send response for request which has been resolved
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(timestamp, "failure:PUT Object", err);
      callback(err);
    });
};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are my hero